# How to modify the color of the white transition page of firefox?

Tags: firefox, browser, colors, themes

When I what to open a website. After I press enter, an all-white page is displayed for a second while I wait for the page to start loading. I understand that it's a very short time but I use dark themes in everything and in the middle of the night it suddenly flashes a white screen and hurts my eyes! so I would love to turn that into black. I guess it should be possible through user.js or something but how?

Comment: [How to change background color of a site opening in a tab](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1139565#answer-918294)

Comment: I tried changing the background colors through the Firefox settings. Search for "Colors". However it did not solve the white flash when opening a new window.